# FLUTTER ERROR Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime-error, get-request

I want to show my data from my API postman to flutter, and I already succeed to get my data with printed it on my terminal, but I cannot show my data in my emulator.

I have this error:

> Exception has occurred._TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

My error is in value like  `value: data[index]['kode']` and `value: data[index]['nama']`

This is my code:

product.dart

```dart
class _pageSuccessState extends State<pageSuccess> {
  var data;
  Future<void> getUserApi() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/produk'),
      headers: headersWithToken,
    );

    var encodeFirst = json.encode(response.body.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = jsonDecode(encodeFirst).toString();
      print(data);
      print('product success');
    } else {
      print('product failed');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Api Course'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getUserApi(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Text('Loading');
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ReusbaleRow(
                                title: 'kode',
                                value: data[index]['kode'].toString(),
                              ),
                              ReusbaleRow(
                                title: 'nama',
                                value: data[index]['nama'].toString(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class ReusbaleRow extends StatelessWidget {
  String title;
  String value;
  ReusbaleRow({Key? key, required this.title, required this.value})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(title as String),
          Text(value as String),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to assign a value of String to a variable type of int. So, you need to change VALUE parameter type from int to String in this ReusableRow widget.

Comment: my Reusable widget is already string,

class ReusbaleRow extends StatelessWidget {
  String title, value;
  ReusbaleRow({Key? key, required this.title, required this.value})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(title),
          Text(value),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Comment: add json response to your post.

Comment: i have added json response but still cannot

Comment: I think, system expects data[index]  to be a List, not  a Map. Can you show how data looks like?

Answer (score -1):

Your var called for parameter 'itemCounter' in your widget ListView is a String type.
Replaces there a List variable or an int value.